# Why this function is not continuous at $z=0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

Let $z=re^{i\theta}$, for $\theta \in (0,2 \pi]$ Let $$
f(z)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
0 & z=0 \\
\frac{r}{\theta} & z \neq 0
\end{array}\right.
$$

Why is it true that for every line going through the origin the function is continuous but at $z=0$ the function is not continuous?

I understand $z=0$ is problematic because this point is not defined well in the complex plane, but I still not understand how to show those arguments formally, by definition.

Comment: Look at $f(\frac 1 n e^{i/n})$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy , you mean substitude $r=\theta=\frac{1}{n}$? and use heine definition?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: But how do we show this via $ f(x,y)= \dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{\tan^{-1}|(y/x)|}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A line going through the origin is defined by $\theta =a$ where $a$ is a constant. You can indeed verify that then as $r \to 0$, $f(z) \to 0$.

However for $z_n= \frac{1}{n} \left(\cos\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)+ i\sin\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)$, you’ll see that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}f(z_n) =n$. So the  limit doesn’t exist.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I still not sure I understand what is the difference between being continuity on a line through the origin VS discontinuity of a point

Comment: Unfortunately, a map can have a limit at a point $c$ on all half lines going to $c$ while not having a global limit at $c$. This is exactly what happens here. You should refer to what means for a complex map to have a limit at a point.

Comment: The function isn’t continuous also on the ray $\theta=2\pi$, by the way.

Comment: @egreg It is. It seems to be that the OP is not using the standard polar decomposition of complex numbers. This is at least my understanding as $\theta =0$ is not part of the definition set of the map.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net If approach points with $\theta=2\pi$ from “above”, the limit is infinite.

Comment: @egreg That is true, but it is not along a ray then.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net According to the function's definition, it is not continuous at all positive reals. Which is a ray isn't it?

Comment: If I understand well the definition of $f$ the positive reals are the one of the ray $\theta=2\pi$.